# SQL Optimal way to subquery one-to-many into individual columns of data in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data that looks like this:

```
WorkTable
---------
WorkId  
1  
2  

ProcessTable
WorkId    Process    ProcessDate  
1         Receive    1/20/2017  
1         Triage     1/21/2017  
1         Triage     1/22/2017  
2         Receive    1/20/2017
```

And I want to create a view that looks like this:

```
WorkId    Received    Triaged  
1         1/20/2017   1/22/2017  
2         1/20/2017   NULL
```

I only need the latest process execution date so with Id 1 I'm picking up 1/22 for Triage because it's the most recent

My current query looks like this but it's very inefficient

```
Select w.WorkId,    
(SELECT     TOP (1) ProcessDate
     FROM          ProcessTable
     WHERE      (w.WorkId = WorkId) AND (Process = 'Receive')
     ORDER BY ProcessDate DESC) AS Received,
(SELECT     TOP (1) ProcessDate
     FROM          ProcessTable
     WHERE      (w.WorkId = WorkId) AND (Process = 'Triage')
     ORDER BY ProcessDate DESC) AS Triaged
From WorkTable w
```

What can I do to make this faster?

Comment: Define "inefficient".  What's the execution plan look like?

Comment: Your sample code has `CreatedDate` but the sample data does not.

Comment: The CreatedDate was a typo.  Fixed it.

Comment: @Donnie Inefficient means butt slow. Execution plan looks butt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated: Using outer [**`apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
select 
    w.WorkId
  , r.Received
  , r.ReceivedBy
  , t.Triaged
  , t.TriagedBy
from WorkTable
  outer apply (
    select top 1 
        Received = i.ProcessDate 
      , ReceivedBy = i.UserName
    from ProcessTable i
    where i.WorkId = w.WorkId
      and i.Process = 'Receive'
    order by i.ProcessDate desc
    ) r
  outer apply (
    select top 1 
        Triaged = i.ProcessDate 
      , TriagedBy = i.UserName
    from ProcessTable i
    where i.WorkId = w.WorkId
      and i.Process = 'Triage'
    order by i.ProcessDate desc
    ) t
```

---

Using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    WorkId 
  , Received = max(case when Process='Receive' then ProcessDate end)
  , Triaged  = max(case when Process='Triage'  then ProcessDate end)
from ProcessTable w
group by WorkId
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/HNB72821

returns (rextester reformats the datetime values, this is formatted back):

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| WorkId |  Received  |  Triaged   |
+--------+------------+------------+
|      1 | 2017-01-20 | 2017-01-22 |
|      2 | 2017-01-20 | NULL       |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

---

or with `pivot()` like so:

```
select 
    WorkId 
  , Receive
  , Triage 
from ProcessTable w
pivot (max(ProcessDate) for Process in ([Receive],[Triage]))p
```

if there are other unused columns in `ProcessTable` you may need to select just the columns you need for the `pivot()` like so:

```
select 
    WorkId 
  , Receive
  , Triage 
from (select WorkId, Process, ProcessDate from ProcessTable) w
pivot (max(ProcessDate) for Process in ([Receive],[Triage]))p
```

Comment: If I have to grab other data from the ProcessTable like a user name, how do i pick up the username from the row with the max processdate and put it in its own column?

Comment: @user3093582 I would use `apply()` for that sort of thing. Updated my answer to include a version for that.

Comment: The apply definitely isn't as fast as the conditional aggregation but it's still half the time of my original query.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join and conditional aggregation.  However, that is tricky, because of the ordering is by `CreatedDate` but the field you want is `ProcessDate`.

I would recommend that you leave your query as-is and create the optimal index index:  `ProcessDate(WorkId, Process, CreatedDate, ProcessDate)`.